# Cypress cy.visit results in 401 unauthorized

Tags: cypress

I am getting a 401 - unauthorized on all my cy.visits that point to a https:// address.

I have tried disabling web security in the cypress.json using:

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

But this had no effect.

My proxy is properly configured.

Non https:// addresses work just fine.
When visiting the pages manually through Chrome, they work  just fine.
I have tried switch Cypress to Electron, but this made no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Chrome version are you using? Have you checked these?
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951 , 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2001

Comment: I am using Chrome 75 and Cypress 3.3.1. in which this issue has already been fixed.

Comment: I found out the problems arise because of the Kerberos environment here.
This is something that requires additional scripting in Cypress, to properly handle the cookies and auth headers.
As soon as I have solved it I will share my solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress support for Kerberos proxy auth is an open issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4667

However, you can use Kerberos with Cypress today by setting up a local proxy. Cypress will hit this proxy using plain HTTP, and the proxy will complete the Kerberos authentication process and pass the content back and forth to your proxy server.

1. Set up https://github.com/genotrance/px according to the README
2. Run Cypress through the default port used by `px`:

   ```
   npm i -g cross-env
   cross-env HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128 cypress open
   ```

For more information about Cypress proxy config, see [the documentation](https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you have come across here is that you have active directory authentication on your web app, and that is why you're getting the 401. To test this, try opening up the app in a Chrome incognito window and if you're prompted for credentials, this is the case.

Here is one solution we are looking at to solve this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-ntlm-auth

There is a bit of config you need to set up in your test suite for this to work, but it's documented quite well.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the whole video especially at the end before trying to use this. It clearly states it does not support single sign on with kerberos token. I'm not saying this is a bad plugin think it looks really good but it does not support all use cases.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rglUBFKG5og](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rglUBFKG5og)